# Layout file on Padrino

Tags: ruby, layout, padrino

Is it possible to use the same layout file across different (mounted) apps without some hackish solution (i.e. sym links) on Padrino ?

Cheers,
Ze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
render :foo, :layout => :"path/to/layout"
```

Comment: This seems a bit redundant if one has several renders in a controller. Is there an option to set layout for the whole controller? Something like `set :layout, :"path/to/layout"` ?

Comment: :layout  :custom    ... will use "views/layouts/custom" ... see http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/controllers#layouts